# mac OS – Creating folders based on part of a filename

Tags: macos

I'm running macOS and looking for a way to quickly sort thousands of jpg files. I need to create folders based on part of filenames and then move those files into it.

Simply, I want to put these files:

```
x_not_relevant_part_of_name.jpg
x_not_relevant_part_of_name.jpg

y_not_relevant_part_of_name.jpg
y_not_relevant_part_of_name.jpg
```

Into these folders:

```
x
y
```

Keep in mind that length of "x" and "y" part of name may be different.

Is there an automatic solution for that in maxOS?
I've tried using Automator and Terminal but i'm not a programmer so I haven't done well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `find` with bash Parameter Substitution in Terminal would likely work:

```
find . -type f -name "*jpg" -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'mkdir -p "${0%%_*}"' {} \; \
-exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%%_*}"' {} \;
```

This uses bash Parameter Substitution with `find` to recursively create directories (if they don't already exist) using the prefix of any filenames matching `jpg`. It takes the characters before the first underscore (`_`), then moves the matching files into the appropriate directory. To use the command simply `cd` into the directory you would like to organize. Keep in mind that without using the `maxdepth` option running the command multiple times can produce more folders; limit the "depth" at which the command can operate using the `maxdepth` option.

```
${parameter%word}
${parameter%%word}
```

> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded
>   value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of
>   parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the
>   longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted.

↳ GNU Bash : [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: Works like a charm! Since you've saved me hours of renaming, I own you a beer. Thank you very much, sir.

Answer (score 4):

I would back up the files first to somewhere safe in case it all goes wrong. Then I would install [homebrew](http://brew.sh) and then install `rename` with:

```
brew install rename
```

Then you can do what you want with this:

```
rename --dry-run -p 's|(^[^_]*)|$1/$1|' *.jpg
```

If that looks correct, remove the `--dry-run` and run it again.

Let's look at that command.

- --dry-run means just say what the command would do without actually doing anything
- -p means create any intermediate paths (i.e. directories) as necessary
- 's|...|' I will explain in a moment
- *.jpg means to run the command on all JPG files.

The funny bit in single quotes is actually a substitution, in its simplest form it is `s|a|b|` which means substitute thing `a` with `b`. In this particular case, the `a` is caret (`^`) which means start of filename and then `[^_]*` means any number of things that are not underscores. As I have surrounded that with parentheses, I can refer back to it in the `b` part as `$1` since it is the first thing in parentheses in `a`. The `b` part means *"whatever was before the underscore"* followed by a slash and *"whatever was before the underscore again"*.

Comment: Hey! Your solution works aswell, however @l'L'l's solution require no additional "software" installing. Thank you very much, sir!

Comment: @MarkSetchell: 