# macOS - Creating Folders based on part of a file name (part 2)

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

This is a follow-up to another thread ([mac OS – Creating folders based on part of a filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678108/mac-os-creating-folders-based-on-part-of-a-filename))

I'm running macOS and looking for a way to quickly sort thousands of JPG files. I need to create folders based on part of filenames and then move those files into it.

Simply, I want to put these files:

```
12345E.JPG
12345E_1.JPG

99876S.JPG
99876S_1.JPG
99876S_2.JPG
```

Into these folders:

```
12345E
99876S
```

Keep in mind that length of "x" and "y" part of name may be different.

Is there an automatic solution for that in maxOS? I've tried using Automator and Terminal but i'm not a programmer so I haven't done well.

I have tried this:

```
find . -type f -name "*jpg" -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'mkdir -p "${0%%_*}"' {} \; \
-exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%%_*}"' {} \;
```

but it doesn't seem to like the .JPG vs .jpg

```
find . -type f -name "*jpg" -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'mkdir -p "${0%%_*}"' {} \; \
-exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%%_*}"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
find . -type f -name "*jpg" -o -name "*JPG" -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c 'mkdir -p "${0%%_*}"' {} \; \
    -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%%_*}"' {} \;
```

The `-o` means or.

Alternatively, you can just run the command twice, once for .jpg and once for .JPG files.

Comment: @Benjamin : It puts 12345E_1.jpg & 12345E_2.jpg in a new folder named "12345E", but leaves 12345E.jpg outside of the new folder. Any suggestions on how to get 12345E.jpg into the "12345E" folder?

Comment: It puts 12345E_1.jpg & 12345E_2.jpg in a new folder named "12345E", but leaves 12345E.jpg outside of the new folder. Any suggestions on how to get 12345E.jpg into the "12345E" folder?